# Screen turns on when I bump phone

Tags: screen, motorola-moto-e, lineageos

I have a Moto E 2015 LTE (surnia) running Lineage OS, Android 7.1.1.  Every time I bump the phone the screen turns on to tell me the time.  I can't find a setting to turn this off.  I couldn't find such a setting in the stock Android either.

<strike>Does anyone know if there is a hidden setting somewhere to control this?  I'd be willing to build my own Lineage ROMS if that is what it took.</strike>  It looks like modifying `com.android.systemui` will be necessary.  Does anyone know how to download that code, and build that APK (perferably without building an entire ROM?)

**EDIT**: A friend clued me in to the fact that this is sort of standard behavior for android phones these days (it's been a while since I had one).  But the question still stands.  I would even be ok with some way to disable the accelerometer completely, if that's what it took.

**EDIT 2**:  I found out that I can disable this behavior by disabling `com.android.systemui`.  I am afraid that is a bit too drastic, so perhaps I will browse some source code to see if I can modify just that app, instead of the whole Lineage ROM.  The question remains though, in case anybody knows how I would go about finding and building source code for `com.android.systemui`.

Comment: What do you mean by when bump the phone?

Comment: I mean it is sitting on the table, and if it is lifted or moved in almost any direction the screen lights up, and becomes touch sensitive.  I find this very obnoxious; I don't want it on unless I turn on the power.

Comment: By "I don't want it on unless I turn on the power", I mean "I don't want the screen to be on or touch sensitive unless I press the power button".

Comment: IDK about your OS, not having used it. I am wondering if this behaviour is triggered by an app. To identify the app - Charge the phone fully and run [wake lock detector](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uzumapps.wakelockdetector) for a few hours (when you don't expect the phone to be used ) watching out for *Screen Wakelock* (clock menu of app). Look out for which apps are trying to keep the screen awake. If nothing shows up, move the phone and immediately go to this screen to see which app is triggering it (I am guessing it to be some exercise monitor app ) . //

Comment: // you could start with installing the app and moving it to see before doing the long test. If you are lucky you can home on to the app. This app can run on [non root devices](https://www.google.co.in/amp/forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-note-5/571286-wakelock-detector-no-root-required.html%3Famp) also. If this hypothesis of it being caused by app is correct, uninstalling that app is far less drastic than what you are prepared for. If not, you have rooted out one possibility !

Comment: Also, in settings maybe under *move* or *ambient display*, see if you have sung like *raise or move to wake*- i see that pixel phones have it from Google

Comment: @beeshyams, thank you for helping.  I checked for those options, but I don't seem to have them.  After installing Wake Lock Detector (which didn't seem to catch what I am observing), I was inspired to start disabling packages en masse to find the package that causing the problem.  Turns out it is `com.android.systemui`.  I will edit post again.

Comment: This sounds awfully lot like Ambient Display at work. It should be in Settings - Display if it exists.

Comment: @Andy YES!  got it.  It was under settings -> display -> ambient display, as you say.  I suppose that beeshyams was talking about the same option but for some reason I didn't see it.  If you post an answer, I will award the bounty.

Comment: Good it's solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour sounds a lot like Ambient Display at work. The toggle for it should be in Settings - Display, if it exists.

[image]

---

**EDIT** the following screenshots are from the OP's phone.  Notice, the "Ambient Display" element does not have a toggle switch in the image below.

[image]

The image below is the submenu that appears upon clicking "Ambient Display".

[image]

Comment: This was annoying me to no end, thank you.  On my android, "ambient display" item doesn't have a switch, but instead opens a sub menu with an option called "Pick-up: pulse notifications on pick-up", which does have a switch to turn off.  However, the "Ambient display" item on my phone has the same sub-text, which is why I had not considered it might be the problem earlier.  I think this a very confusing UI, because I *do* want "wake screen when you recieve notifications", but that is not all that "Ambient display" does on my android.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @rexroni Motorola phones are known for Moto Display, their own, more powerful implementation of Ambient Display, and those enhanced subfunctions you mentioned are part of it, presumably backed up by extra sensors. That's why they are also getting more than just a simple toggle even when on a custom ROM.

Comment: @rexroni good to hear that the issue's solved! If possible, could you provide the screenshot for Motorola's Ambient Display setting? You may also edit this answer and update it with your screenshot to make this answer more correct!